# how to find anchor tag inside a div in a loop

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, anchor

I'm new to beautiful_soup, what I want is to print all the anchor tags(only links) that are present inside all the classes named 'brandcchild', which is present inside class 'brandGroup choose_a'.I have successfully accessed class 'brandGroup choose_a' but was not able to get all the links present inside its sub-classes i.e. class = "brandChild".

```html
<div id="brandGroup" class="brandGroup choose_a">
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
<div>
```

```
a= soup.find('div',class_="brandGroup choose_a")
for x in a:
    anchor=x.find_all('div',class_="brandChild")
    link=anchor.find('a')
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
for link in soup.select('div.brandGroup.choose_a div.brandChild a'):
    print(link['href'])
```